# Modify Amount of Pending Contribution (Price Set)

Tags: civicontribute

Seems like if a donor makes a pay later commitment using a price set, we cannot manually go in and change the amount. Is that intended? Instead of the editable donation amount, I just see this.

[image]

Comment: is this useful in your use case? if so i will add as an Answer. https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor

Comment: Did anyone tell you that you are amazing today? Because you are amazing!

Comment: Blush - thanks for adding that comment. will re-add as an answer. and am sharing the gratitude with someone else who reminded me about it recently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the [Line Item editor extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-editor), which provides editing option for line items in Contributions, may be what you are after